# Extracting last word from rows within index column

Tags: python, pandas

I would need advice on how to extract the last word from index values.

My dataset looks like

```
                                                  Exercise 1        Exercise 2  ....
Homeworks                             Teacher      

/Users/school/Maths/Exercises on LD       GK         This exercise...   The second exercise needs ...         
... rows ...                              GK
/Users/school/Maths/Exercises on DE       MG
... rows ...                              MG
/Users/school/Maths/Exercises on GE       GD
... rows ...                              GD
```

and similar other paths' names. Exercise 1 and 2 are columns; Homeworks and Teacher are index columns.

I would need to rename the value within the index column as follows (expected output):

```
                           Exercise 1        Exercise 2  ....
   Homeworks    Teacher                               
    
    LD             GK        This exercise...   The second exercise needs ...
    ... rows ...   GK
    DE             MG
    ... rows ...   MG
    GE             GD
    ... rows ...   GD
```

I have done this:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.str.extract('\s(\w)\/$')[0]], 
                                         names=['Homeworks', 'Teacher'])
```

I had to use a Multindex since I have two columns as indices.
Could you please tell me how to get the table above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Given the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Homeworks': ['//Users//school//Maths//Exercises1 on LD', '//Users//school//Maths//Exercises2 on DE', '//Users//school//Maths//Exercises3 on GE'],
        'Teacher': ['GK', 'MG', 'GD'],
        'Exercise 1': ['This exercise', 'This exercise', 'This exercise'],
        'Exercise 2': ['The second exercise needs', 'The second exercise needs', 'The second exercise needs']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(['Homeworks', 'Teacher'], inplace=True)

# display(df)
                                                     Exercise 1                 Exercise 2
Homeworks                                Teacher                                          
//Users//school//Maths//Exercises1 on LD GK       This exercise  The second exercise needs
//Users//school//Maths//Exercises2 on DE MG       This exercise  The second exercise needs
//Users//school//Maths//Exercises3 on GE GD       This exercise  The second exercise needs
```

### Update `df`:

- Reset the index
- Create a new column from the last 2 letters of `Homeworks`
- Optionally, extract the path from `Homeworks`
- Set the new index

```py
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['Drives'] = df.Homeworks.str[-2:]  # take the last to letters
df['Paths'] = df.Homeworks.str.split(expand=True)[0]  # split on space and take the value at index 0
df.drop(columns=['Homeworks'], inplace=True)
df.set_index(['Drives', 'Teacher'], inplace=True)  # set the index

# display(df)
                   Exercise 1                 Exercise 2                               Paths
Drives Teacher                                                                              
LD     GK       This exercise  The second exercise needs  //Users//school//Maths//Exercises1
DE     MG       This exercise  The second exercise needs  //Users//school//Maths//Exercises2
GE     GD       This exercise  The second exercise needs  //Users//school//Maths//Exercises3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop "Homeworks" and assign them to their new name.

```
for i in range(0,len(df["Homeworks"])):
    df["Homeworks"][i] = newstring
```

being newstring your regex string from df["Homeworks"][i]

Comment: This will not work as written, because `Homeworks` is part of a multiindex.